# User rights of a super user and the administrator

Tags: leopard, user-account, administrator

I'm used to "classic" unixoid user right system with a machine running a normal user, as main account, and a super user (or root account), just for maintenance or configuration purposes.

Then I was really wondered about Mac OS X (I'm currently running Leopard). What purpose has the admin user account? If I'm installing something via console (as a normal user, not admin) I have apparently to log in as admin and then log in as root user (via `sudo -s` because `su` strangely doesn't work).

Does anyone know what the main reason for this is or how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is by design. A non-admin user is defined by not being able to use sudo (and the graphical equivalent in the mac windowmanager). You can still enter the admin user and password using `sudo -u` or the graphical equivalent but short of compromising/modifying the built in controls, that's how the system is designed to work.

The `su` command doesn't work as you expect since the [root user in Mac OS X is disabled by default](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528) for security reasons. Sudo has enhanced logging and `sudo -s` gets you the same shell as `su -` would when a root user is enabled.

So if you don't want to change to using sudo you can enable root on your mac.

Comment: This is just this kind of manual I searched for!

Comment: Thanks to @KeithB for pointing out errors that are now corrected in this answer.

Comment: I'd like to add that in Mac OS X, there **is a difference** between admin and sudo. My machine is set up so that I can use sudo just fine, but I'm not an admin according to the GUI.